# Input edit text IP number

Tags: java, android

I have a problem when converting to string in edit text.

**Input edit text IP number**

```
public class Client extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String TAG = Client.class.getSimpleName();

public static final int SERVERPORT = 3000;


ClientThread clientThread;
Thread thread;
TextView messageTv;
String text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    messageTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageTv);
    EditText SERVER_IP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ipnumber);
     text = SERVER_IP.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: *`have a problem when convert to string in edit text`* What problem? Your question is unclear provide more information about your problem

Comment: your question is not clear, please add more details to your question e.g. show layout textview and edittext are added

Comment: Yeah i am sorry for my question is to short, i have jus fix it... Thank you brother

Comment: try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(editTextAddress.getText().toString());
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

Comment: that is my solution from that problem, my question before how to convert edit text string for IP text

Answer (score 0):

Your question not very clear but here is how you do it

```
EditText eTxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ipnumber);
TextView tView=new TextView(this);
tView.setText("Your Text is="+eTxt.getText());
setContentView(tView);
```

Comment: Thank you brother

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is a bit uncleared but by looking at your code try to specify the layout from where the "ipnumber" EditText belongs to, as suggested here http://android-er.blogspot.co.za/2011/02/how-to-retrieve-string-from-edittext.html

Comment: Thank you brother